# How to define that function result is possibly undefined in typescript

Tags: typescript

consider

```
const funct = (t: number): string | undefined => (t > 0 ? 'asd' : undefined);
```

the inferred type for the result of `funct` is string, but should be string | undefined. Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: You should enable _strictNullChecks_, otherwise everything considered possibly undefined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated after lajos-gallay's comments.**

I think you're doing it right, but you need enable `strictNullChecks`.

I tried your code like this:

```
const funct = (t: number): string | undefined => (t > 0 ? 'asd' : undefined);
const result = funct(15);
console.log(result.length);
```

and the inferred type of `result` was `string | undefined`, 
so the last line throws `[ts] Object is possibly undefined`.

I have `"strictNullChecks": true` under `compilerOptions` in my `tsconfig.json`.

Comment: yes, but only when you have strict mode enabled. Check your tsconfig.json and add '"strict": true' or '"strictNullChecks": true' to the compiler options.

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html

Comment: The flag in tsconfig was indeed set to false.